# Delegate callbacks in dispatch_queues

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

According to the [AWS SDK documentation](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1ZZHQHSD0O3SF/Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-Asynchronously-Part-IV-Grand-Central-Dispatch-GCD-Best), the following will ***not*** work:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    S3PutObjectRequest *request = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:objectKey inBucket:bucketName];
    request.data = data;
    request.delegate = self;

    [s3Client putObject:request];
});
```

meaning, the delegate methods will not be called, due to the following reason:

> The block in this GCD queue will be executed in the background thread,
>   which has its own run loop, separate from the one on the main thread.
>   The delegate will be registered with the background thread's run loop
>   that is responsible for calling the AmazonServiceRequestDelegate
>   method. However, putObject: immediately returns and the entire block
>   also returns. When the block finishes its execution, the background
>   thread will be collected by GCD, and nothing that is responsible for
>   calling the delegate methods will be left behind. That's why the above
>   code sample doesn't work.

And it's true, the delegate methods are never called for that block of code. However, I expected this to work:

```
self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{

    S3PutObjectRequest *request = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:objectKey inBucket:bucketName];
    request.data = data;
    request.delegate = self;

    [s3Client putObject:request];
});
```

Notice that I'm retaining the queue, so after the block returns, the queue sticks around. However, this still doesn't work - the delegate callbacks are never called. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Serial Dispatch Queue, but it doesn't mean that there should be a thread attached to the queue, the system manager the background thread and it will provide a thread to some queue to execute the code you push to the queue.

The Serial Dispatch Queue guarantee the works you push to it is executed one by one but it doesn't guarantee the thread which do the work is the same.

So you face the same problem when using Global Concurrent Dispatch Queues.